# Webpack 5 Module Federation Without Hosting

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-5

Recently came across webpack 5 Module Federation Plugin, but this came across my mind,

That is to federate the module without hosting it.

The reason for this question is because running a webpack dev server for each modules to be federated seems to eat up quite some amount of resources during development.

Understand that we can deploy the build to a remote server might solve the issue

Is there any other possible alternative?

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason you have to host it with webpack dev server. You could just run the build and copy your outputs to a common folder and just serve it with a simple http server like `npx http-server`

Comment: Hi @dtabuenc, but I would need to run a http-server for each module that I want to federate. Example if I'm using yarn workspace with monorepo concept, with 6 packages,
I would need to run 6 http-server in my local machine.
I can run one http-server and copy all builds into separate folders, but that is not really a good developer experience.

Any recommended solution?

Answer (score 0):

In case of monorepo, in dev you could have your remote apps all built and copied to the same folder with different names for the entry file used by Module federation (filename property in module federation plugin).

Then in your container app you declare those entry filenames for each of the modules and have a server that serve all those entry point files and associated apps.

You will have only one server that serves all the remotes. That's great if you don't have to modify your remotes on change.

You can have that on a persistant server, you just have to change the url of entrypoints on your Module Federation plugin (container app).